# MIPS Assembly language Power Program

Tags: function, assembly, mips

im learning mips and i dont understand what to put inside the (complete the codes) section and my teacher confuses the hell outta everyone so its a struggle trying to understand therefore any help is welcomed

```
# Power program
# ----------------------------------
# Data Segment
.data
var_x:      .word   3

var_y:      .word   5   
result:     .word   0

# ----------------------------------
# Text/Code Segment

.text
.globl  main
main:
    lw  $a0, var_x  # load word var_x in memory to $a0
    lw  $a1, var_y  # load word var_y in memory to $a1
    jal power       # call the function power   
    sw  $v0, result # save word from $v0 to result in memory

    # complete other codes here to print result in console window

    # -----
    # Done, exit program.
    li  $v0, 10     # call code for exit
    syscall         # system call
.end main

# ----------------------------------
#   power
# arguments:    $a0 = x
#       $a1 = y
# return:   $v0 = x^y
# ----------------------------------

.globl  power
power:  
        add   $t0,$zero,$zero   # initialize $t0 = 0, $t0 is used to record how many times we do the operations of multiplication
        addi $v0,$v0,1          # set initial value of $v0 = 1
power_loop: beq $t0, $a1, exit_L    
        mul $v0,$v0,$a0         # multiple $v0 and $a0 into $v0 
        addi $t0,$t0,1          # update the value of $t0   
        j   power_loop
exit_L:     jr  $ra
.end    power
```

Comment: Looks like all that is expected is to print the result? Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: in the #complete other codes here to print result in console window line under that do I have to write anything is what is confusing me because #lines are provided by the teachers so it means that I have to write something for the code

Comment: Yes, you need to write code that prints the result. It says so in the comment.

Comment: oh,i misread the earlier post my bad and may I ask what do I write since im pretty bad at mips

Comment: MARS has a system call for printing integers.  Read the docs, and/or google `site:stackoverflow.com print integer mips`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move your sum from `$v0` to `$a0`. Then, just append this to your code to print the results in the output box/console.

```
add $a0, $v0, $zero     # copy the value into the arg register $a0
#print the result (in $a0) in decimal to the output
li  $v0, 1              # service 1 is print integer
syscall                 # print_int($a0)
```

Comment: If you overwrite `$v0` with the call number first, this will always print `1`.